# "I will forgive you" vs "I forgive you"

Tags: grammar

Will is used to make immediate decisions but I heard a native say this:

> I forgive you

instead of

> I will forgive you

why did he say it like that?

Comment: He said it like that because 'I forgive you' is the present tense, while when you say 'I will forgive you' it means that the speaker (person a) will eventually forgive the subject (person b). However, it implies that the subject is not immediately being forgiven.

Comment: Yeah but for example, we say I'll go there and not I go there.

Comment: The word I'll means I will, which is in the future. Also sometimes people do use I go there, such as the following: 'I go to work in London' (If they are currently working in London) But 'I will go to work in London' means that the speaker is not currently working in London, but plans to do so in the future.

Comment: _I will forgive you_ could also imply 'I'm willing to forgive you this time (but I may not be so forgiving if you do it again).'

Comment: @coolguy as a native speaker, I'm not completely sure why! That's just what we say with *forgive*. If I were to take a guess, I'd say that *forgive* can be seen as an action (*I will forgive* meaning you're going to do that in the future), or a state (*I forgive you* = *I have forgiven you* = the action of forgiving happened in the past, and still affects the present). It's a little similar to *I believe you*, which isn't so much an action of performing belief, and more the state you're in where that belief *exists*. And the present simple is used for ongoing states (*I live here* etc.)